# An elegant solution for handling Custom Augmentation Layer's batch_size being None during init?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm doing a scientific ML project and wrote a custom layer extending from `base_layer.BaseRandomLayer`. In this layer, I generate some noise data based on physics (wind wave noises), which will be added to the input data. Since I need to generate `batch_size` number of noise data, the logic makes use of `batch_size` (`inputs.shape[0]`).

The problem is when I initialise the layer with input_shape, `batch_size` goes in as `None` and so it throws an error. This is how it is being initiliased:

```py
input_layer = tf.keras.layers.Input((601, 1))
noise_layer = NoiseLayer(500)(input_layer)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs = input_layer, outputs = noise_layer)
```

I believe during initialisation Keras goes through the code in order to figure out the output data shape. For now, I found a crude solution where I simple use an If statement, and simply return the inputs if batch_size is 0, like so:

```py
if inputs.shape[0] == None:
    return inputs
```

Another solution I found is to specify `batch_size` when I make `input_layer`, but I'd like to keep it more general.

I was wondering if there is any other (better or best practice) solution to this problem. I guess my solution works fine, and I cannot think of any edge cases since in real training the batch_size will never be `None`.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: You need to use `tf.shape(inputs)[0]` in order to work with dynamic batch size during training.

Comment: Hi @Frightera thanks for your reply. Yeah, I have seen that when i was googling, but my model trains without a problem with the above code. What difference does it make?

Comment: inputs.shape[0] will return None, tf.shape(inputs)[0] will return the number of elements in that batch. Isn’t that what you’ve wanted?

Comment: But does it return batch_size during initialisation as well? Specifically, when I run this code `noise_layer = NoiseLayer(500)(input_layer)`, it doesn't return the `batch_size` (because there is no batch size!).

Comment: You shouldn't care about the batch size during initialization, it should be fine if you can dynamically use it during training. For this, you need to add your layer definition, right now it is vague what exactly you want to achieve.